# Why "alle beide"?

Tags: grammaticality

If `beide` means both, then why use `alle beide`? `All both` sounds rather redundant.

Is it some form of emphasis, or is there another reason?

Comment: "All two of them" would probably Sound more natural in englisch.

Comment: "both of them" would sound natural "all two of them " does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is mainly for emphasis, particularly if you want to point out that it is *only* two.

Answer (score 0):

Angenommen Du leitest Filmaufnahmen für den Film "Die 3 Musketiere", aber gestern meldete sich einer telefonisch, er käme nicht, weil er krank sei.

Heute fragst Du Deinen Assistenten, ob die Schauspieler da sind und er, über das angekündigte Fernbleiben informiert, antwortet: "Ja, alle beide". Er sagt damit einerseits, dass es alle sind - alle unter Berücksichtigung der Umstände - und dass es 2 sind, also auch, dass er informiert darüber ist, dass wegen der Erkrankung heute nur mit zweien zu rechnen ist.

Dagegen wäre "Ja, beide." eine unvollständige Antwort, da ja eigentlich mit dreien zu rechnen gewesen wäre, und dann hätte man sagen müssen "Zwei."  oder "Erst zwei".

Comment: Das stimmt, aber es ist ein spezieller Fall, in dem jemand sehr präzise mit der Sprache umgeht, präziser als umgangssprachlich üblich. *Alle beide* wird sicher häufiger im Sinne von *beide* gebraucht als so.

Comment: Bitte beantworte die Frage in der Sprache, in der sie gestellt wurde. Also Englisch.

Comment: @infinitezero: Nutz doch deepL, wenn Du kein Deutsch verstehst: "Suppose you're in charge of filming for the movie "The 3 Musketeers", but yesterday someone called and said he didn't come because he was sick.

Today you ask your assistant if the actors are there and he, informed about the announced absence, answers: "Yes, both of them". On the one hand he says that there are all of them - all considering the circumstances - and that there are 2 of them, so also that he is informed that because of the illness only two can be expected today." …

Comment: ... "On the other hand, "Yes, both" would be an incomplete answer, since actually three would have been expected, and then one would have had to say "Two" or "First two"." https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en

Comment: Es geht hier nicht darum, was ich verstehe oder nicht verstehe, sondern einen Wissensschatz für möglichst viele Leute aufzubauen. Wenn jemand auf Englisch nach der Frage sucht, und dann eine deutsche Antwort vorfindet, bringt das nichts. https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/should-the-language-of-an-answer-match-the-language-used-in-the-question

Comment: Und wenn er auf Deutsch sucht? Es ist ja anzunehmen, dass jemand der Informationen zur dt. Sprache sucht v.a. Deutsch kann - ob er Englisch kann ist ja nicht gesagt. Wenn Du den Link schon postest, dann kennst Du ja meinen Standpunkt und musst Deine Unzufriedenheit damit ja nicht unter jedem meiner Beiträge dokumentieren. Es sollte Dir aber leicht fallen noch viele Gelegenheiten zu finden, Ausdauer zu beweisen.